# How can I download e-mails w/ Mozilla Thunderbird onto my hard drive & upload to new server?

Tags: email

My family's company is moving from an old, washed up server to a new cloud server with a different web hosting company.

I need to download emails from the current web host's server for 14 email boxes to my hard drive, so they can be uploaded to the new web host's server!

I have searched different add-ons for Mozilla Thunderbird, but I am unable to figure out the proper way to download individual e-mail profiles and save them on my hard drive.

I have Googled, but tutorials I have followed are too convoluted or have not worked.

Any guidance in this regard would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking to do, exactly. Are you trying to get all emails that exist on the old server in a form that you can import to the new server? If that's the case, I'm presuming you have been and will be using IMAP as the mail server protocol? If that's not what you're trying to do, please clarify, as you also talk about "individual email profiles".

Comment: Thanks @tubedogg -- I was attempting to install all of the e-mails from the old host on my server, and transfer them to the new server.  I accomplished this by copying them to the /local folders/ in Mozilla Thunderbird.  But for some reason, while the old host's webmail still works, I'm unable to receive any more e-mails.  So the emails from Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday will be lost, I believe, and I will not be able to upload them to the new server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two best tools for shifting email from one server to another would have to be [imapsync](https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync) and [offlineimap](http://offlineimap.org/). Of these offlineimap probably has the best instructions and assistance.

You could either transfer the emails directly or, with a little setup, download them to your Mac and then back up to the new server.

Comment: Thank you, @Tony Williams, for taking the time to respond!